# APR sendfile for Tomcat 8 does not send small files

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, sendfile, apr

I am trying to sendFiles by APR module of tomcat as described in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/aio.html  It works really well for relatively large files(videos, large pdfs etc). However it is unable to send small files(30-40 KB). It does not seem like a mime type issue because I have tested it with txt files. 30KB txt files could not be sent whereas 10MB txts are just fine.

```
request.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.sendfile.filename", filepath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
request.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.sendfile.start", 0);
request.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.sendfile.end",Files.size(filepath));
```

Am I missing somekind of configuration?

Comment: Can you verify the value of the `org.apache.tomcat.sendfile.support` attribute in the request before you try to set these attributes?

Comment: I have already verified the value but it did not work. So I changed to nginx to serve static files instead. Thank you for your kind concern.

Comment: I'd prefer that you report this to the Tomcat users' mailing list and get it fixed if it is indeed a bug.